# Drupal Image styles thumbnail, medium, large to default dimenssions

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

My drupal creates thumbnails of my uploaded image (thumbnail, medium and large). How can I stop drupal from creating these?

I don't want to have redimensioned images, I want original size.

PS: Drupal creates 3 images per uploaded image, so, for me are lots of nodes.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This question belongs on drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Closing this as you've [posted on Drupal SE](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78425/image-styles-thumbnail-medium-large-to-default-dimenssions) and accepted another answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image styles isn't generated until the first time you use them. So, if you only use the original image in your theme and also inside your administration the `thumbnail`, `medium` and `large` images will never be created.

To use the original image in the backend you will have to go to `structure/types/manage/<contentent_type>/display` and change the image style that is used for displaying your field.